# Proof that a graph isn't hamiltonian

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

I can't do that. I have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBMF7.jpg) graph. I think that it doesn't contain hamiltonian cycle.

[image: graph]

I have no idea how I can proof it. I can't find proper subset $S$ to do it with Chvatal-Erdos theorem. I can't use Ore and Dirac theorem because, I can't conclude that "a graph is not hamiltonian because it doesn't meet Ore & Dirac conditions" - it's not true, so actually I don't know any other theorems I could use. I will really appreciate any kind of help, hint, anything.

Comment: So you're saying that I'm supposed to check every potential hamiltonian cycle /circut starting with "subdivided" edges ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each of the edges incident on the degree $2$ vertices must be used in any Hamilton cycle. Then, in any Hamilton cycle, the top vertex has degree at least $3$, which is impossible...

Comment: I'm really sorry that i don't know but second sentence is little unclear for me. What is top vertex ?

Comment: The top vertex in the figure of your question. The vertex adjacent to all three degree 2 vertices...